# civimobile too old , while I've the latest version

Tags: wordpress, api, install, civimobile

I've got the message civimobileapi to old, please install a recent version

That's what I did....No result

FYI:

I've downloaded the latest recent software versions from github 
Both: civomobileapi and CiviCRM WP REST API

I've use 'com.agiliway.civimobileapi' without any extra as :master or version number.

I've the latest civicrm version

yes, I've cleaned the catch

I've install the civimobileapi in different dirs (for sure in the ext)

But nothing happens. Still ....civimobileapi is to old please use a ne version

Any solution, will be much appreciated!

Comment: guessing this should be "too old" rather than 'to old'

Comment: also if you have issues with this app it may be a good time to try the new one by AgileWare https://agileware.com.au/civicontact/

Comment: Sorry, i am Dutch :-)
Thanks for your advice

Comment: It would be helpful to have some screenshots. Also did you clear the civicrm caches?